# Copy of certain fields from one table to another in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to accomplish a copy of some row's fields from one table to another. I'm trying that with this query:

```
update table1
set goal = t2.Goal, notes = t2.Notes
from
    Table2 AS t2
    join Table3 AS t3
        ON t3.ID = t2.PID
    join table1 as t1
        on t1.title = Title 
        and Name like t1.name + '%'
```

I need to join these first two tables to get the name and titles with the third one which uses title and name as identifiers. This query works, but not for all rows in table1 - there is some amount of rows, which have no copied data.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Name and Title belong to which tables?

Comment: Name is from Table2 and Title from Table3

Comment: just map your column: JOIN table1 as t1 ON t1.title = t3.Title 
    AND t2.Name like t1.name + '%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
update t1
set t1.goal = t2.Goal, t1.notes = t2.Notes
from
    Table2 AS t2
    JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t3.ID = t2.PID
    JOIN table1 as t1 ON t1.title = t3.Title 
    AND t2.Name like t1.name + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
update Table1 
  set Goal = t2.Goal,
      Notes = t2.Notes
from
   Table2 AS t2
   join Table3 AS t3
        ON t3.ID = t2.PID 
where  
   Table1.Title = t3.Title AND
   t2.Name like (Table1.Name + '%')
```

Here is an example based on your schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a08cc/1

Comment: I think this will throw a syntax error. From my experience after the `UPDATE` keyword you have to specify the alias of the table that you want to modify data for. Then you "call" this table in the `FROM` part of the query.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I totaly forgot on that...It's edited so its should work now, thanks for suggesting